# PostgreSQL OLD not working in after update statement level trigger

Tags: python, django, postgresql, triggers, postgresql-triggers

I'm trying to update course points by the sum of course's lessons points.
It is working perfectly if I do select particular course ID like this:

```
BEGIN   

UPDATE course
SET points = (SELECT COALESCE(SUM("lesson"."points"), 0) AS "sum_points" FROM "course" LEFT OUTER JOIN "lesson" ON ("course"."id" = "lesson"."course_id") WHERE "course"."id" = 7) 
WHERE "course"."id" = 7;
RETURN NULL;
                
END;
```

But not working with OLD which is the updating instance. I want to update points of whichever course is being updated.

```
BEGIN   

UPDATE course
SET points = (SELECT COALESCE(SUM("lesson"."points"), 0) AS "sum_points" FROM "course" LEFT OUTER JOIN "lesson" ON ("course"."id" = "lesson"."course_id") WHERE "course"."id" = OLD."course_id")
WHERE "course"."id" = OLD."course_id";
RETURN NULL;
            
END;
```

I'm using django-pgtriggers: https://pypi.org/project/django-pgtrigger/

```
@pgtrigger.register(
    pgtrigger.Trigger(
        name="add_course_point",
        level=pgtrigger.Statement,
        when=pgtrigger.After,
        operation=pgtrigger.Update,
        func=f"""
            UPDATE course
            SET points = (SELECT COALESCE(SUM("lesson"."points"), 0) AS "sum_points" FROM "course" LEFT OUTER JOIN "lesson" ON ("course"."id" = "lesson"."course_id") WHERE "course"."id" = OLD."course_id")
            WHERE "course"."id" = OLD."course_id";
            RETURN NULL;
            """
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OLD` and `NEW` are always `NULL` in case of `Statement level`.
[image]

Replace `level=pgtrigger.Statement` with `level=pgtrigger.Row`

```
@pgtrigger.register(
    pgtrigger.Trigger(
        name="add_course_point",
        level=pgtrigger.Row,
        when=pgtrigger.After,
        operation=pgtrigger.Update,
        func=f"""
            UPDATE course
            SET points = (SELECT COALESCE(SUM("lesson"."points"), 0) AS "sum_points" FROM "course" LEFT OUTER JOIN "lesson" ON ("course"."id" = "lesson"."course_id") WHERE "course"."id" = OLD."course_id")
            WHERE "course"."id" = OLD."course_id";
            RETURN NULL;
            """
    )
)
```

or add `referencing=pgtrigger.Referencing(old='old_table_name')` and then modify your function.

Comment: I have changed the statement level to row level, but actually found out that problem was another. In order to solve it, I deleted _pgtrigger_should_ignore function from pgAdmin4 and migrated again. Working perfectly now, thanks for the answer Philippe)

Answer (score 0):

I have registered 2 triggers. The first one is ***before update*** trigger for inserted lessons. The second is ***after update*** trigger for updated and deleted lessons. **Course points are **incremented** or **decremented** by the **sum** of its **lessons points** after all.**

```
@pgtrigger.register(
        pgtrigger.Trigger(
        name="add_course_point",
        operation=pgtrigger.Insert,
        level=pgtrigger.Row,
        when=pgtrigger.Before,
        func=f"""
            UPDATE course
            SET points = (points + NEW.points)
            WHERE "course"."id" = NEW.course_id;
            RETURN NEW;
            """,
    ),
    pgtrigger.Trigger(
        name="update_course_point",
        operation=(pgtrigger.Update | pgtrigger.Delete),
        level=pgtrigger.Row,
        when=pgtrigger.After,
        func=f"""
            UPDATE course
            SET points = (SELECT COALESCE(SUM("lesson"."points"), 0) AS "sum_points" FROM "course" LEFT OUTER JOIN "lesson" ON ("course"."id" = "lesson"."course_id") WHERE "course"."id" = OLD.course_id)
            WHERE "course"."id" = OLD.course_id;
            RETURN NULL;
            """,
    ),
)
```